# php session information lost when website opens new tab in Chrome 34

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

I run a small website with a link as follows:

```
<a href="/page.php" target="_blank">foo</a>
```

When using Chrome 34 (and apparently also Firefox 29), the session information is not available when in page.php.

My question is: is this something that other users also experience, and how do I fix it (server side or client side)?

Comment: did u start a session (`session()`) in the beginning of the file page.php?

Comment: if you mean session_start(), the answer is yes

Comment: sorry for mistyping, that what i meant exactly, is it happening only when u r using these two particular versions?

Comment: just to be clear, this happens only on this specific page of the site, which also happens to be the only page that is called by a new tab. There have been no code modification for some time and the error occurs specifically on (the newly released) Chrome 34

Comment: Go f12 -> network -> headers. See the session id in cookie header of the request.